# Windbg + IDA: calculate an address in a module

Tags: reverse-engineering, windbg, offset, ida

I'm debugging remotely a windows XP machine. One of my drivers is loaded at address 0xb2c4c000 up to 0xb2cb9680.

Now when I open my driver in IDA, the offset I want to set a breakpoint on is at 00017619.

How can I effectively match my IDA address into windbg?

I've tried the obvious which is to sum 0xb2c4c000 + 00017619 = 0xB2C635F7 and disassemble that address using the 'u' command in windbg. But the results did not match the assembly in IDA.

On the side question: is there a way to cancel a command that is running in windbg? Several times I've ran commands that took ages to process, I would like to be able to cancel them if needed. So I can keep working.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: regarding your 2nd question - well-behaved extensions handle ctrl-break (alt. ctrl-c) (which is the way to cancel a command taking too long)

Comment: Which offset did you look at in IDA? I assume you didn't look at the file offset... you need to have a look at the base address for your driver module, then first subtract that from the offset.

Answer (score 3):

The recent versions of IDA Pro allow you to debug device drivers through its WinDbg debugger plugin.

Another alternative is that you can rebase your database to match the base of the loaded module and like that you have one to one mapping between idb and windbg session.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding incorrectly. Since IDA assumes 10000  as Entry point correct way to add is

0xb2c4c000 + 00007619 (10000 is substracted)